# Why does not StyleCop Analyzers require xml docunentation

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2017, stylecop

I've "upgraded" from the old StyleCop VS extension to the StyleCop.Analyzers NuGet package. After the change I am no longer recieving any warning for missing element documentation, but I see all other StyleCop violations as warnings as expected (including SA1633 - Require file header)

I 'm using VS 2017 and my solution is composed of several projects (it's a Xamarin Forms solution with Android and IOS targets). I've tried to incorporate StyleCop.Analyzers as best I can with a shared StyleCop.json file (located at the solution leven and added "as link" to each individual project. The Build Action is set to AdditilaFiles inn all projects) and a shared GlobalSupressions.cs (also added as a link from the common solution level file).

The GlobalSupression.cs contains two suppressions:

```
[assembly: System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage(
    "StyleCop.CSharp.SpacingRules", 
    "SA1028:Code must not contain trailing whitespace", 
    Justification = "New rule that requires too much work to implement")]

[assembly: System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage(
    "StyleCop.CSharp.DocumentationRules",
    "SA1652:Enable XML documentation output",
    Justification = "Could not get copyright file header to work properly")]
```

Without the last one StyleCop issues a SA1652 warning for the xml file header in each file. The file header looks like this:

```
// -----------------------------------------------------------------
// <copyright file="GlobalSuppressions.cs" company="MyCompany">
// Copyright (c) MyCompany. All rights reserved.
// </copyright>
// -----------------------------------------------------------------
```

My StyleCop.json

```
{
  "$schema": "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/DotNetAnalyzers/StyleCopAnalyzers/master/StyleCop.Analyzers/StyleCop.Analyzers/Settings/stylecop.schema.json",
  "settings": {
    "documentationRules": {
      "xmlHeader": true,
      "companyName": "MyCompany",
      "copyrightText": "Copyright (c) {companyName}. All rights reserved.",
      "headerDecoration": "-----------------------------------------------------------------",

      "documentInterfaces": true,
      "documentInternalElements": true,
      "documentExposedElements": true,
      "documentPrivateElements": true,
      "documentPrivateFields": true
    }
  }
}
```

I can't detect any difference between including the last 5 lines or not. No warnings are issued for missing documentation (and I know there are many missing)

Cato

Answer (score 0):

Upgrading to StyleCop.Analyzers 1.1 beta 4 solved the problem (althoug warnings only appear for open documents)